# Origin of “on tilt”

Tags: etymology

Farlex Dictionary of Idiom gives the following definition about the expression:

***[on tilt](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+tilt)***:

> In a reckless or rash state; acting without proper care, attention, or consideration.

and adds that:

> Originally used in reference to poker players who begin making
> reckless decisions after experiencing either good or bad luck.
> Primarily heard in US.

But [Gambling with the Myth of the American Dream](https://books.google.it/books?id=-vrqBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Aaron M. Duncan, suggests that the sense of  “tilt” originated  from the game of pinball and was later adopted by poker players with the meaning suggested above.

Unluckily both sources don’t give further details about how and when the expression evolved.

So did the expression “on tilt” really originate in pinball-machines arcades and from there moved to smoky poker-players  rooms to become later a more colloquial expression? Poker, after all, is a much older game than pinball.

Comment: I think the current answers are likely correct, but I wonder if the term ***originally*** came into parlance from Miguel de Cervantes' **Don Quixote**: *Aren't you too smart to go around tilting at windmills? I'm not going to fight this issue. I've wasted too much of my life tilting at windmills.*

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket That's a possibility because while "tilting" in that context is a reference to the sport of jousting, the phrase "full tilt" appears to derive from the jousting meaning of tilt rather than the leaning meaning of the word. The online game "full tilt poker" started at about the time that "on tilt" appeared to arise in the poker world.

Comment: @DavidHammen That's what I'm thinking too.  Now, since I wasn't around in the 1600's (despite some claims to the contrary), I'm not sure if Cervantes brought the word into parlance or if wasn't already commonly in use at the time.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Cervantes wrote in Spanish. It's the translation to English that results in the phrase "tilting at windmills".

Comment: @DavidHammen Yep... the English translation with the word *"tilting"* came out in the early 1600's, if my reproduction is accurate (I found a few mistakes, so I do question its accuracy).  I lent out my Spanish edition to someone who apparently didn't return it... which words did Cervantes use for this phrase in the original Spanish publication?  As a side note, the translations to several other languages that I bought years ago are so filled with errors that the meanings and beauty of many of Cervantes' clever nuances are totally lost.

Answer (score 15):

The OED's first citation for *tilt* with reference to pinball machines is:

> [**1934**   Billboard (Cincinnati) 17 Nov. 67 (advt.)    Anti-tilt.]

The view among poker players is that being/going/putting "on tilt" was adopted/adapted from pinball machines. Unless use of the expression for emotion-based play in poker can be document earlier than the arrival of pinball, I would accept this explanation. The earliest example of "on tilt" used in poker that I've found is 1978 (see below).

(1) Examples of *like pinball machine on tilt / titled like a pinball machine*  meaning  *uncontrolled motion* /*out of control* / *drunk*:

> **Not Crazy—Tilted**
>
> "**Tilted like a pinball machine" may be on the way to becoming a
> handy part of American slang.** The syndicated cartoon feature, "Out
> Boarding House—with Major Hoople," showed the boarding house bunch
> ganging up on the old windbag. One of the boys ask him, "Are you
> **tilted again like a pinball machine**?" (From *The Detroit News*, October
> 28.) [*The Billboard*, November 20, **1943**](https://books.google.com/books?id=vQwEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT59&dq=like%20a%20pinball%20machine%20on%20tilt&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqoZ239JP1AhVHT98KHbAFDdcQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=like%20a%20pinball%20machine%20on%20tilt&f=false)

> The liquor gurgled down George's gullet—and oh, boy! He lighted up
> **like a pinball machine on tilt**!  [*A. A. Grapevine*, vol. 23, p.17](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_A_Grapevine/1iYpAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22he%20lighted%20up%20like%22) and partly in the [search page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pinball%20machine%20on%20tilt%22&sxsrf=AOaemvKPo_Nfblpi__EDi0YE4fY2BsVjmA%3A1641153738622&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1950%2Ccd_max%3A1970&tbm=bks) (1966) (Snippet Views) [1944 was the year of the first issue]

> John was like a **pinball machine on tilt, out of control**, and he
> raced into the soundproof recording room. [Bob Woodward; *Wired: The
> Short Life & Fast Times of John Belushi*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wired/ZWcPqPzYUCsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bob%20woodward%20wired%20%22pinball%22%20out%20of%20control&pg=PP20&printsec=frontcover) (1984)

> Then again, maybe the real issue is that I'm below in the stuffy cabin
> of our sailboat right now, which is acting like a **pinball machine on
> tilt (I'm the pinball)**. [Janna Cawrse Esarey; *The Motion of the
> Ocean*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Motion_of_the_Ocean/eoWwYCT4_P0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pinball%20machine%20on%20tilt%22&pg=PA56&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> She was sitting in full lotus pose, and her mind seemed so focused in
> comparison, it made me feel like a **pinball machine on tilt.**
> [Christoffel Hendrickx; *On My Way Home, vol. 1*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/On_My_Way_Home/wLW9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pinball%20machine%20on%20tilt%22&pg=PT189&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

(2) Attribution/likening of poker players' *on tilt* state to *tilt* on a pinball machine:

> Poker playing involves a lot of aggression, "psyching" others out and
> often the use of personal insults. [Snippet View](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Human_Behavior/EeVHAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22psyching%22%20others%20out%20%22human%20behavior%22&dq=%22psyching%22%20others%20out%20%22human%20behavior%22&printsec=frontcover)
>
> The goals of these  insults are to **put players on
> tilt.** [Snippet View](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Human_Behavior/EeVHAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22insults%20are%20to%20put%20players%20on%20tilt.%22&dq=%22insults%20are%20to%20put%20players%20on%20tilt.%22&printsec=frontcover)
>
> Mike's crazy antics couldn't **put him on tilt**, since he was too
> occupied with thinking up a play to bust john...  [Snippet View](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Human_Behavior/EeVHAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=put%20players%20on%20tilt)
>
> David Hyano in *Human Behavior*, vol. 8 (**1978**) [Snippet with copyright date](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Human_Behavior/EeVHAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=copyright)

> **The concept of tilt comes from traditional pinball machines**. To keep
> players from damaging the machines by lifting them to alter the course
> of the ball, the manufacturers placed sensors inside that disabled the
> machine if it was violently jostled. The flippers stopped working, the
> lights went off, and the word "tilt" flashed at numerous places on the
> layout. **The origin of tilt in pinball is apt** because what's going on
> in our brain in moments of **tilt** is like a shaken pinball machines.
> When the emotional center of the brain starts pinging, the limbic
> system (specifically the amygdala) shuts down the prefrontal cortext.
> **We light up...then we shut down our cognitive control center**. [Annie
> Duke; *Thinking in Bets: Making Smarter Decisions When You Don't Have
> All the Facts*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thinking_in_Bets/CI-RDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on%20tilt%22%20origin&pg=PA198&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> When a player goes **on "tilt,”** like a pinball machine, he or she stops
> operating and makes rash moves. ([p.19](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Beyond_Bluffs/hWZkV7FWuN0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pinball%20machine%22%20%22on%20tilt%22&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover))
>
> **Playing on Tilt**
>
> When you abuse a pinball machine, it will **go on tilt** and stop
> playing . The same thing will happen with many poker players. If they
> feel abused, they will **go on tilt** and stop playing their best
> game.  [James McKenna; *Beyond Bluffs: Master the Mysteries of
> Poker*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Beyond_Bluffs/hWZkV7FWuN0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pinball%20machine%22%20%22on%20tilt%22&pg=PA19&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> Poker players have a different vocabulary and views when it comes to
> the subject of problem gambling. Poker players tend not to speak of
> think of themselves in terms of addition. Rather poker players use the
> phrase "**tilt**." ... The term originated from the game of pinball, when
> frustrated players would attempt to cheat the game by tilting the
> pinball machine [Aaron Duncan; *Gambling with the Myth of the American
> Dream*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gambling_with_the_Myth_of_the_American_D/tvzqBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=on%20tilt%20pinball&pg=PT48&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

> Broadly speaking, letting emotion influence you is called **being on
> tilt,** or **tilting**. The term presumably comes from pinball: ram a
> pinball machine too hard with your hip, and the machine shuts down and
> you lose. [C. Baldassarre and R. Burgess; *The Pocket Idiot's Guide to
> Texas Hold'em*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Pocket_Idiot_s_Guide_to_Texas_Hold_e/waXPt4wp_4oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on%20tilt%22%20pinball&pg=PT95&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> As the poker players would say if asked to make **pinball puns**, I'm
> **on tilt**. [Adam Ruben; *Pinball Wizards*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pinball_Wizards/PyLXDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on%20tilt%22%20pinball&pg=PT120&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> The term **tilt** comes from a pinball **tilt**. A player on "**tilt**" is
> one who's playing very badly as a result of some emotional trauma.
> [Gary Carson; *The Complete Book of Hold 'Em Poker*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Complete_Book_of_Hold_Em_Poker/xuG9egFLh_wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on%20tilt%22%20pinball&pg=PA203&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> They go "**on tilt**.” Sort of like a pinball machine, except with
> pinball it only costs you a quarter. [Daniel Kimberg; *Serious
> Poker*](http://pinball) (2002)

> It is enough to make good players **go on tilt**. What is **tilt**?
> Did you ever play pinball? Remember what happens if you jostle the
> pinball machine too much? **You cause it to shut down**. [Ashley Adams;
> *Winning 7-Card Stud*](http://PA98) (2003)

Comment: So, apparently, the missing link here is the evidence that early pinball players were also habitual poker players.

Comment: I'm not sure you had to be a "habitual" player -- you don't have to play pinball a lot to learn what "tilt" means :-). One of the examples alludes to poker players making "pinball puns." I do think the "on" part of the expression was part of the adaptation to a poker's player's emotional state.

Comment: Now you don’t, but in the early years when pinball became popular,  to go  “on tilt” was restricted to pinball users. From there, somehow, it spread to other games (apparently mainly in poker) and finally to common usage. I am not sure this is the real and only story…but I’d like to know.

Comment: I've added a Bob Woodward example with "on tilt" pinball usage meaning "out of control."

Comment: It may prove difficult to find a definitive answer. We'd need to know the motivation of the first poker players to use it.

Comment: A funny thing is that pinball players don't "go on tilt". If you shove and push the game too much, you tilted it. At that point it's frozen and you just let go and wait. No one ever says they're "on tilt". There's no way it would mean out-of-control in a pinball sense. It's a case of misunderstanding a term before borrowing, which seems common enough.

Comment: @OwenReynolds It may be alluding to the fact that you no longer  control the ball in the tilt state; that ball is "out of (your) control (with the flippers)."

Comment: @OwenReynolds - it is not the pinball  players that go on tilt, but the machine itself. The poker player is, in that sense, like the pinball machine.

Comment: @user66974 One of the examples describes, for the poker player: "We light up...then we shut down out cognitive control center." Another has   "he or she stops operating and makes rash moves."

Comment: I don’t think it is a difficult metaphor. The real issue is how and when it moved from its original place to elsewhere. Why did poker players adopt it, and not football or basket players for instance? My guess is that probably pinball machines were placed in places (pubs, bars etc.) where people met to play cards also. But I have no evidence

Comment: @user66974 In my multi-state years of pinball playing I'm telling you nothing was ever "on tilt" and tilt never meant an emotional out-of-control feeling. It's just bang, you've been busted, now wait for it to drain. My point is that I think it was borrowed by poker players who weren't pinball players but saw those big flashing TILTS and had the general "tilt means bad" idea.

Comment: @user66974 Before video games, pinball was extremely popular, just about everyone was familiar with it, especially teenage and young adult men. So there would be few poker players who didn't know pinball jargon.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. In my youth, it was quite a marvel, a first taste of the kind of user interaction with feedback we'd later see in video games. In searching for examples, I came across this paper: [Pinball wizard: the case of a pinball machine addict](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1529048/) from 1992.

Answer (score 5):

From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=tilt):

> **tilt (n.1)**
>
> Pinball machine sense is from 1934

The **'tilt' mechanism was invented in 1934** as a direct answer to the problem of players physically lifting and shaking the games.

So I believe the **psychological** meaning of *on tilt* in poker (also chess and esports) originates from the **physical** meaning of *(on) tilt* in pinball. There aren't any instances of the psychological sense of *tilt* being used in poker before 1934, so this seems to be the only logical explanation.

> "Tilt" originates from pinball tables, where altering the slope of the
> table would affect the path of the ball. As this is essentially
> cheating, pinball tables were designed with a tilt sensor, which when
> triggered would disable all scoring mechanisms (and usually the
> flippers as well), forfeiting any further action with that ball.
>
> A player that's frustrated may shove the table in anger, triggering
> the tilt sensor. (Gentle nudging was a common tactic, if one was
> familiar enough with a particular pinball table to know the
> sensitivity of the sensor.) So the expression "on tilt" started to be
> used to mean a player who's lost his cool.
>
> [Greg B from Gaming Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190507/what-is-the-meaning-of-tilting-or-being-on-tilt)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the idiom myself, but a bit of googling soon found...

> [**Tilt = Anger + Bad Play**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22definition%20of%20tilt%20as%20defined%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJoW1XdfbTm6YtlLVEVlv1A6lHFPA%3A1641124603670&ei=-5LRYfGzKKOFhbIPp_W8sAU&ved=0ahUKEwixnaLIgZP1AhWjQkEAHac6D1YQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22definition%20of%20tilt%20as%20defined%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQugxYugxg2hJoAHAAeACAAVyIAagBkgEBMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) <sup>(The Mental Game of Poker, 2011)</sup>
> *The definition of tilt as defined by conventional poker wisdom is too broad. Sometimes tilt just means playing badly; but it also can mean playing badly because of winning, or playing too loose, conservatively, ...*

...followed by several pages going into detail about different types of "tilt", within which the specific usage *[to be] **on tilt*** occurs repeatedly.

I looked at several other instances of the sequence [***were on tilt***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were%20on%20tilt%22) in Google Books, and most of them were obviously related to either poker playing specifically, or gambling / risk-taking sport in general, so an origin in gambling looks likely to me. But I'd say it's essentially a fairly transparent metaphoric usage implying that a player has been ***knocked off balance, destabilised*** ("lost his cool"), and is thus not playing well / sensibly.

---

EDIT
Seeing various answers and comments relating to *tilting at windmills, rushing full-tilt, tilting pinball tables*, I think it's worth reproducing [an actual dictionary definition](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+tilt) of this specific sense...

> **on tilt**
> *In a reckless or rash state; acting without proper care, attention, or consideration.*
> **Originally used in reference to poker players** who begin making reckless decisions after experiencing either good or bad luck. **Primarily heard in US.**

Comment: What was the date of the earliest poker/gambling use of "on tilt" that you found? Were any pre-pinball? The earliest example I've found for "on tilt" in poker is 1978.

Comment: We can go back to at least 1603 ([The Non-dramatic Works of Thomas Dekker](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22broach+is+on+tilt%22)) for written instances of references to things / people / beer barrels being "on tilt". But the collocation **on tilt** had little currency until the 80s anyway, which to me strongly suggests that the *current* usage (almost exclusively with this "Bad Play" sense) doesn't have much to do with tilting pinball tables (their heyday was earlier, in the 50s / 60s). And the metaphoric imagery is so transparent it doesn't need much "explaining" for this "origin".

Comment: ...besides which, I used to be a bit of a Pinball Wizard myself back in the 60s. Weaker players might tilt the machine, but I never heard anyone talk about being ***being on tilt***. And in the current usage, if you're on tilt, *at least you are actually **playing**, albeit **badly***. If you tilt a pinball table, it's ***game over*** - a completely different situation.

Comment: The content of your edit was previously provided by the OP in their question.

Comment: @user66974: The OP talks a lot about pinball tables, which I would respectfully suggest is ***totally irrelevant*** to the usage under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

My suspiscion is that it derives from the expression [going full tilt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full%20tilt#h1) meaning to be running, driving, sailing or working at full speed or "flat out" The Merriam Webster entry under the above link says that the earliest recorded usage of it comes from around 1670 which greatly precedes both pinball tables and poker as a game.

Interestingly there is evidence of an online poker site called "Full Tilt Poker" which suggests that, in some cultures at least, "full tilt" is either a version of poker (in the way that Texas Hold 'Em is a version) or a description of a playing style. I wouldn't know I don't play poker.

There is a suggestion online that the wider expression "full tilt" comes from jousting which was also known as "tilting". For example think of the accepted English description of Don Quixote which has him "tilting at windmills".

Comment: That’s an interesting  assumption, my only concern is that “at full tilt” has a more positive connotation, while “on tilt” has definitely a negative one.

Comment: The connotations of "at full tilt" aren't necessarily positive. If someone is travelling at full tilt on horseback or in a horse-drawn vehicle, particularly on a rough track or poorly maintained road, they can be considered to be placing themselves and any passengers or bystanders at great risk. The same would be true of a car driver "going at full tilt" on a crowded urban thoroughfare. Even a factory "going at full tilt" could be in danger of sacrificing quality and/or safety for the sake of higher production.

Comment: Yeah, I would guess that the term derives much of its flavor from jousting.

Comment: I think *full tilt* and *on tilt* are very different and I’d be amazed if that’s the etymology we’re looking for. Regarding the *full tilt* site I suspect it is just a play on words, and the name “mostly” hints at “intense/fast/lively” poker with only a slight nod to the *on tilt* phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Etymonline gives The earliest meaning of *tilt* is *tyltan* in Old English, from proto-German.  It goes on to cite old Norse *tyllast* = *to trip*, and Middle Dutch *touteren* with in the 1590s a sense of *to push over* or *to fall over*.  In this context, tilting in the middle ages was associated with the military action of mounted knights, armed with lances, charging each other in the attempt do knock each other over.  It became a royal sport of 'tilting', which came near to being the end of King Henry VIII at one famous tournement.

The word became a familiar to at least British English in the expression *tilting at windmills* to describe any pointless or deluded action, referring, as it did to Don Quixote's charge at at a windmill under the delusion that its sails were charging knights in the comic epic of that name by Cervantes.

The Cambridge English Dictionary gives a good account of both the verb and the noun in their modern uses.  It seems likely that the gaming uses of the question ca be readily understood again the historical background of the word, including the luckless Don Quixote.

Comment: In jousting, tilt is a trade term mean to go at the adversary with the pole, or whatever it's called.

Comment: @Lambie Exactly.

Comment: @Lambie - lance is an accepted term. Noun, not to be confused with the verb to lance.

Comment: @Tim, yep, that's what I couldn't remember. Thanks!